# Why website load time goes high after traffic?

Tags: page-load-time

I have using a dedicated server, website is also fully optimized.but whenever I share blog links on Facebook, site load time increse drastically. When traffic comes, site load time goes hoto 50 sec. Couldn't find the solution. Please help. [Here is the websites](http://irablogging.com)

Comment: For the first time your website take upto 5 seconds to load, without getting link from fb

Comment: I think there might be a issue with your hosting services